# Testing across multiple activities with Espresso Null Pointer

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-testing

I am running a test that takes me in to another activity. When I get to that I need to wait for a dialog to disappear.

```
  public class StressTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<DashboardActivity> {

DashboardActivity activity;
ConsoleActivity consoleActivity;


public StressTest() {
    super(DashboardActivity.class);
}

public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    activity = getActivity();
}

public void testRun() throws InterruptedException {
    schedule();
    quickstart();
    IP.enterIP();
<-----------FAILS HERE FROM A NPE------------------->
    while (consoleActivity.getConnectDialog() != null && consoleActivity.getConnectDialog().isShown()){
        Thread.sleep(
    } 
}
```

As you can see, I am starting in `DashboardActivity`. Then Once in to `ConsoleActivity`, I need to check for `ConnectDialog`. How can I do this without getting a NPE?

### EDIT

```
 public void testRun() throws InterruptedException {
    schedule();
    quickstart();
    IP.enterIP();
    Thread.sleep(500);

    getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Collection<Activity> resumedActivities = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED);
            Log.d("RESUMED ACTIVITY SIZE", "" + resumedActivities.size());

            if(resumedActivities.size() == 1){
                consoleActivity = (ConsoleActivity) resumedActivities.iterator().next();
            } else {

            }
        }
    });
    while (consoleActivity.getConnectDialog() != null && consoleActivity.getConnectDialog().isShown()){
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
```

### LOGS

```
Log.d("ACTIVITES", "getClass: " + resumedActivities.iterator().next().getClass().getName() + " ConsoleActivity: " + ConsoleActivity.class.getName());
```

printed :

```
 D/ACTIVITES﹕ getClass: com.android.lonewolf.activity.console.ConsoleActivity ConsoleActivity: com.android.lonewolf.activity.console.ConsoleActivity
```

Comment: Where do you instantiate consoleAcitvity?

Comment: @cbrulak I haven't instantiated it. I tried `consoleActivity = getActivity();` but got syntax error

Comment: well, that's your error then, right there. You've declared it but haven't instantiated it, then you call it. That's the NPE.

Comment: @Binghammer  You said: "As you can see, I am starting in DashboardActivity."  Where do we see that?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky, The first line of code in the snippet: ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<DashboardActivity> will open the test in the DashboardActivity

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You receive a NullPointerException because your `consoleActivity` isn't initialized. 
Put code below before `while()`.

**EDITED**

```
Iterator<Activity> iterator;
Activity activity;
Collection<Activity> resumedActivities;
getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
            resumedActivities = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance()
                .getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED);
            iterator = resumedActivities.iterator();
            }
        }
    });
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    activity = iterator.next();
    if(activity.getClass().getName().equals(ConsoleActivity.class.getName())){
        consoleActivity = (ConsoleActivity)activity;
    }
}
```

And import ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry:

```
import com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry;
```

Comment: I am still receiving the npe. I checked the size of resumedActivities. and it is only one

Comment: Check what Activity class you have inside `activity.getClass().getName()`. You can also compare it with `ConsoleActivity.class.getName()` in case of multiply activities.

Comment: The activities appear to be the same. Look at my *LOGS* update.

Comment: Yes I am still getting npe